# PHP find the max value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, max

I have an array where I need to find the max value. I have looked at many examples and logged questions here but I can not seem to find an answer to my specific issue.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => Test Test Test
            [yaxis] => 19875.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => Test1
            [yaxis] => 10375.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => Test2
            [yaxis] => 76000.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => test3
            [yaxis] => 4451.61
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => test4
            [yaxis] => 6225.81
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => test5
            [yaxis] => 3000.00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [xaxis] => test6
            [yaxis] => 2000.00
        )

)
```

I have tried the following:

```
echo max($data[0]['yaxis']);
```

This will give an error obviously

```
echo max($data[0]);
```

This returns 'Test Test Test' instead of the correct '76000'

```
echo max($data);
```

This returns 'array'

Comment: foreach + compare last highest value with the current one.

Comment: `$yaxisMax = max(array_column($arr, 'yaxis'));`

Answer (score 0):

`max()` works for simple arrays. Turn yours into one.

```php
$values = array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el['yaxis'];
}, $data)

echo max($values);
```

You can make it into a one liner too.

```php
echo max(array_map(function ($el) { return $el['yaxis']; }, $data));
```

```php
echo max(array_map(fn($el) => $el['yaxis'], $data));
```